# Error message while trying to install Tensorflow for GPU using Anaconda

Tags: tensorflow, windows-10, anaconda

I am trying to install Tensorflow for GPU using Anaconda on my Windows 10 system. Running

```
conda create --name tf_gpu tensorflow-gpu
```

I get:

```
Downloading and Extracting Packages
tensorflow-base-1.12 | 180.8 MB  | #########################################################1                   |  75%

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\miroslaw.bartkowiak\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\pkgs\\tensorflow-base-1.12.0-gpu_py36h6e53903_0\\Lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\include\\tensorflow\\include\\external\\eigen_archive\\unsupported\\Eigen\\src\\SpecialFunctions\\arch\\CUDA\\CudaSpecialFunctions.h'
```

I'd appreciate your help ...

Comment: Have you installed Cuda drivers on your system?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is Windows long path name support.
For some reason MS leave it off.

For Windows 10 Pro or above, run the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit).
Go to Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Filesystem.
Change the Enable Win32 long paths setting to Enabled and reboot.

For Windows 10 Home, you have to change the registry.
Hive: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
Set LongPathsEnabled to 1
Reboot.

Then try again.
Good luck!